# C# / ASP.NET - Override Browse Event handler on FileUpload control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, file-upload

I'm currently using an [ASP.NET File Upload control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227677%28v=vs.140%29.aspx). This works great, but I'd like to remove the current `Upload` button and put its logic into the `Browse...` button instead.

Is there a way to overload the `Browse...` button's logic?

Currently:

[image: Photo upload current example]

I'd like to have this:

[image: No upload button]

When the user clicks the `Open` button in the File Upload box, the `Upload` buttons' logic fires:

[image: File to upload]

Upon clicking `Open`, the following code triggers in C# Code behind.

```
protected void override btnSomeOverriddenControl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (multipleFile.HasFiles)
    {
        foreach (var file in multipleFile.PostedFiles)
        {

            //do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You want the browse button to turn into an upload button after the person gets some files from the file system?

Comment: Yep! One less click, essentially.

Comment: You have to inject some css on the buton and change its inner html. You can do this easly with jquery or javascript.